# CP-odd and CP-even interference terms in the Higgs sector

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs

I have often heard people state that the interference terms between CP-odd and CP-even terms in Higgs boson decays vanish, but - not being a theorist myself - I have some problems in coming up with the explanation of why this is the case.

Assume a Lagrangian of the form
\begin{align}
  \mathcal{L} &= \left\{a_1V_\mu V^\mu + a_2V_{\mu\nu}V^{\mu\nu}+bV_{\mu\nu}\tilde{V}^{\mu\nu}\right\}X_0
\end{align}
where $V$ is some vector boson (like $W$ or $Z$), $X_0$ is the Higgs boson field, 
\begin{align}
  V_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\mu V_\nu - \partial_\nu V_\mu 
\end{align}
is the reduced field strength tensor, and
\begin{align}
\tilde{V}^{\mu\nu} &= \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}V^{\rho\sigma}
\end{align}
is the dual tensor. The Lagrangian and the notation was stolen from the [Higgs Characterization model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6464).

Now consider a simple decay of the form $H\to VV$.

I would like to understand how I can see that the interference terms proportional to $a_1b$ and $a_2b$ vanish in the Matrix Element, but my QFT courses are long in the past and mostly forgotten by now, and hence I don't know where to start.

**Edit**

With some research, I was able to determine that the vertex factor must look something like 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{V}^{\mu\nu} & \propto a_1 g^{\mu\nu}+a_2\left(q_{1}^{\mu}q_{2}^{\nu}-q_{1}q_{2}g^{\mu\nu}\right)+b\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}q_{1\rho}q_{2\sigma}
\end{align}
where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the SM and BSM CP-even couplings, and $b$ is a BSM CP-odd coupling.

This means that the matrix element for the $H\to VV$ vertex will look like this:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{M} & \propto\sum_{\lambda,\eta}\mathcal{V}_{\mu\nu}\epsilon_{1\lambda}^{\ast\mu}\epsilon_{2\eta}^{\ast\nu}
\end{align}

Now, however, I'm again lost. Why do the terms proportional to $a_1b$ and $a_2b$ vanish in $|M|^2$?

Comment: Hint: what's epsilon contacted with something symmetric, either g or q1 q2 q1 q2?

Comment: Ah gotcha, because it's the totally antisymmetric tensor. That's extremely helpful, thanks a lot!